# When using "tls-alpn-01" challenge for let's encrypt certs in kubernetes using traefik, I'm getting "acme: error: 400 Timeout during connect"

Tags: ssl, kubernetes-helm, traefik-ingress, alpn, acme

I'm following the [tutorial](https://blog.baeke.info/2019/05/24/quick-overview-of-traefik-ingress-controller-installation/) to use traefik as the ingress and ingress controller for Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster. I'm using terraform to deploy the traefik (version 1.7.24) helm chart.

```
resource "helm_release" "traefik" {
  name       = "traefik"
  namespace  = "traefik"
  repository = "https://charts.helm.sh/stable"
  chart      = "traefik"
  version    = "1.87.2"
  values = [<<EOF
loadBalancerIP: "50.100.200.300"
service:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: "aks-rg"
kubernetes:
  ingressClass: traefik
  ingressEndpoint: 
    useDefaultPublishedService: true
dashboard:
  enabled: true
  domain: traefik.mydomain.tld
  ingress: 
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik    
metrics:
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
rbac:
  enabled: true
ssl:
  enabled: true
  enforced: true
acme:
  enabled: true
  email: admin@mydomain.tld
  staging: true
  tlsChallenge: true
  entrypoint: https
  ports: "443:443"
  challengeType: tls-alpn-01
  onHostRule: true
  domains:
    enabled: true
    domainsList: 
      - main: "mydomain.tld"
      - sans:
        - "traefik.mydomain.tld" 
EOF
  ]
}
```

The DNS records are correctly pointed to the AKS Load Balancer IP.

When I check the traefik logs, I could see that "tls-alpn-01" challenge fails with the following error:

```
{"level":"error","msg":"Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"mydomain.tld,traefik.mydomain.tld\" : unable to generate a certificatefor the domains [mydomain.tld traefik.mydomain.tld]: acme: Error -\u003e One or more domains had a problem:\n[mydomain.tld] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem), url: \n[traefik.mydomain.tld] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem), url: \n","time":"2021-02-26T02:32:05Z"}
```

Full log is given below:

```
{"level":"info","msg":"Using TOML configuration file /config/traefik.toml","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"No tls.defaultCertificate given for https: using the first item in tls.certificates as a fallback.","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Traefik version v1.7.24 built on 2020-03-25_04:34:11PM","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/basics/#collected-data\n","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Preparing server traefik \u0026{Address::8080 TLS:\u003cnil\u003e Redirect:\u003cnil\u003e Auth:\u003cnil\u003e WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:\u003cnil\u003e Compress:false ProxyProtocol:\u003cnil\u003e ForwardedHeaders:0xc000851700} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Preparing server http \u0026{Address::80 TLS:\u003cnil\u003e Redirect:0xc0000b1b80 Auth:\u003cnil\u003e WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:\u003cnil\u003e Compress:true ProxyProtocol:\u003cnil\u003e ForwardedHeaders:0xc0008516a0} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Starting server on :8080","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Preparing server https \u0026{Address::443 TLS:0xc000431e60 Redirect:\u003cnil\u003e Auth:\u003cnil\u003e WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:\u003cnil\u003e Compress:true ProxyProtocol:\u003cnil\u003e ForwardedHeaders:0xc0008516c0} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Starting provider configuration.ProviderAggregator {}","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Starting server on :80","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Starting server on :443","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Starting provider *kubernetes.Provider {\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":[],\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":0,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Endpoint\":\"\",\"Token\":\"\",\"CertAuthFilePath\":\"\",\"DisablePassHostHeaders\":false,\"EnablePassTLSCert\":false,\"Namespaces\":null,\"LabelSelector\":\"\",\"IngressClass\":\"traefik\",\"IngressEndpoint\":{\"IP\":\"\",\"Hostname\":\"\",\"PublishedService\":\"traefik/traefik\"},\"ThrottleDuration\":0}","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"ingress label selector is: \"\"","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Creating in-cluster Provider client","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Starting provider *acme.Provider {\"Email\":\"admin@mydomain.tld\",\"ACMELogging\":false,\"CAServer\":\"https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"Storage\":\"/acme/acme.json\",\"EntryPoint\":\"https\",\"KeyType\":\"RSA4096\",\"OnHostRule\":true,\"OnDemand\":false,\"DNSChallenge\":null,\"HTTPChallenge\":null,\"TLSChallenge\":{},\"Domains\":[{\"Main\":\"mydomain.tld\",\"SANs\":[\"traefik.mydomain.tld\"]}],\"Store\":{}}","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Testing certificate renew...","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Server configuration reloaded on :8080","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Server configuration reloaded on :80","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Server configuration reloaded on :443","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:38Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Server configuration reloaded on :443","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:39Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Server configuration reloaded on :8080","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:39Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Server configuration reloaded on :80","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:39Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Register...","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:42Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Updated status on ingress traefik/traefik-dashboard","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:42Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Server configuration reloaded on :443","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:55Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Server configuration reloaded on :8080","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:55Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Server configuration reloaded on :80","time":"2021-02-26T02:31:55Z"}
{"level":"error","msg":"Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"mydomain.tld,traefik.mydomain.tld\" : unable to generate a certificatefor the domains [mydomain.tld traefik.mydomain.tld]: acme: Error -\u003e One or more domains had a problem:\n[mydomain.tld] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem), url: \n[traefik.mydomain.tld] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem), url: \n","time":"2021-02-26T02:32:05Z"}
```

I have even added a "AllowAll" rule in AKS LoadBalancer NSG (firewall). But still tls-alpn-01 validation is facing the timeout error. The ssl certificate generation doesn't happen and my website is using the default example.com expired ssl certificate.

I can confirm that telnet to port 443 of mydomain.tld also works fine.

PS: I don't want to use "dns-01" challenge for ssl certificate as the dns provider doesn't have the APIs for let's encrypt. I can't use "http-01" as these are backend servers which do not have any web server.

Any help is much appreciated. I would also like to know how the tls-alpn-01 challenge works.

Comment: were you able to solve this? i'm facing a similar issue

Comment: I couldn't solve it using tls-alpn-01 challenge. I went with dns-01 challenge to solve it in the end.